# Set the value of a final field in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a method in IntelliJ IDEA and in debug mode I need to set the value of a final field. Is possible to achieve in some way?

This is the image of my IDE in debug mode, I'm trying to change the value of the `collectionId` variable.

[image: IDE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it is doable. Adapt & type the below in the evaluate/modify Intellij dialog:

```
Field finalF = this.getClass().getDeclaredField( "m_field" );
finalF.setAccessible(true);
finalF.setInt(this, newValue);
```

Answer (score 7):

IntelliJ IDEA (and Java debugger API) [doesn't support it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185903). Comment from the responsible developer:

> There's a check in Java JDI code (`com.sun.tools.jdi.ObjectReferenceImpl#setValue`) that does not allow to change value of a final field, it was added long ago.

[ObjectReferenceImpl.java#L236](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/jdi/ObjectReferenceImpl.java#L236):

```
        // Make sure the field is valid
        ((ReferenceTypeImpl)referenceType()).validateFieldSet(field);
```

[ReferenceTypeImpl.java#L614](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/94318f9185757cc33d2b8d527d36be26ac6b7582/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/jdi/ReferenceTypeImpl.java#L614):

```
    void validateFieldSet(Field field) {
        validateFieldAccess(field);
        if (field.isFinal()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set value of final field");
        }
    }
```

The reason why it's not allowed is that changing final fields may lead to inconsistency in behavior: some values may be "inlined" by the compiler already and will not be changed.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to get a the point of the variable , because it is a very long expression and I don't have the required classes to make to in java Code.

Comment: Sorry, it's a debugger API limitation, there is no way to do it. You've asked the question, got the answer that is not satisfying, but the only valid one. So [feel free to accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).